# How can I get a parent element to take the dimensions of its children?

Tags: css

This is an on-going concern of mine.  I tried the normal fix of

```css
display: inline-block
```

but it did not work.  Here is the code.  The containing div is called `container-1` and the div I want it to contain along with dimensions is called `mi_holder`:

```css
#container-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#mi_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1">
  I am inside
  <div id='mi_holder'>
    But I am outside :(
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works, because `inline-block` establishes a block formatting context. Please explain what "did not work" means.

Comment: OK, I understood you meant `#mi_holder` didn't wrap its floated contents. The problem is that `position: relative` moves an element but surrounding elements don't "see" it.

Comment: It's not completely clear what the issue is from the link. But have you tried `overflow: auto;` on the containing `container-1` element? That's the usual way to make sure a parent element wraps around its contained elements.

Comment: Nope. I just use `clear` property itself on the element I want to appear beneath another. Most solutions use `overflow: auto` to solve the problem of parent elements filing to 'contain' their children.

Comment: @cadegalt Yes, margins seem the best solution. I have removed part of the code to make it clear the problem is not related to the floats, feel free to edit if you think I removed too much.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `top: 100px;` to `margin-top: 100px;`

Comment: updated, probably was the better choice.  Was thinking too quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this give the result you want:

```css
#container-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#mi_holder {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1">
  I am inside
  <div id='mi_holder'>
    And I am no longer outside :)
  </div>
</div>
```